# A-priori bound on parabolic PDE that doesn't depend on end time

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

I have a PDE
$$u_t = a(x,t)u_{xx} + b(x,t)u_{x} + c(x,t)u + f$$
where the coefficients are in parabolic Holder space $\widetilde{C}^{0, \alpha}(I \times [0,T])$ where $I=[0,2\pi]$. The a-priori bound (eg. from Krylov's book) is
$$\lVert u \rVert_{\widetilde{C}^{2, \alpha}(I \times [0,T])} \leq C\left(\lVert f \rVert_{\widetilde{C}^{0, \alpha}(I \times [0,T])} + \lVert u_0 \rVert_{\widetilde{C}^{2, \alpha}(I \times [0,T])}\right)$$
where the constant $C$ depends on the endtime $T.$

Does anyone know how to remove this dependence on $T$? I think there might be a way to do it by considering the PDE obtained when we change the coefficients somehow but am not sure.

Comment: What is $I$? An interval in the real line? Bounded or not?

Comment: @YangMills yes, $I=[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: What is the norm of $f$ and $u_0$ in the estimate?

Comment: Sorry for the omissions. @timur I edited it.

Comment: My naive guess is that you need a decay of $f$ in time, and use a norm for $f$ that takes into account how $C$ grows with time.

Comment: Don't you have to impose some assumption on $u(0,\cdot)$ and $u(2\pi,\cdot)$ to get the estimate?

Comment: And what happens if you look at simple cases where for example $a$ and $b$ are identically zero and $f$ is equal to $1$?

Comment: Not sure what your end goal is, but it is often useful to consider $u$ on time intervalls of fixed length such as $[t_0, t_0+1]$ for all $t_0 > 0$.

Comment: While I don't think this question is quite suitable for this site, I will add this: If $c \leq 0$, then you have the maximum principle. Once you are bounded, you should be able to bootstrap to whatever smoothness $f$ and the coefficients allow. (I don't know exactly what you want to do.) If $c \geq 0$, then in general it can cause exponential growth, but you can `undo' its contribution by considering the PDE for $e^{t\gamma} u$ instead of $u$, where $\gamma = \max c$.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible in general.

Consider the simple case when $a=1$, $b=0$, $c=1$,$f=1$, and $u_{0}=0$.

You have not specified boundary conditions: suppose $u$ is $2\pi$-periodic in $x$.

The problem becomes
$$
\partial_{t}u=\partial_{xx}u+u+1\text{ on }\left(0,2\pi\right)\times\left(0,T\right), \quad u(x,0)=0.
$$
The the solution is
$$
u\left(x,t\right)=\exp\left(t\right)-1.
$$
Thus
$$
\left\Vert u\right\Vert _{C^{n}\left(\left[0,2\pi\right]\times\left[0,T\right]\right)}\geq \exp(T)-1,
$$
for any $n\geq0$, whereas
$$
\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{C^{0,\alpha}\left(\left[0,2\pi\right]\times\left[0,T\right]\right)}=1.
$$

If you wish to impose Dirichlet boundary conditions, $u\left(0,t\right)=u\left(2\pi,t\right)=0$,
then choose (for example) $f(x,t)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)$, and $c=\frac{5}{4}$, so that the solution becomes $u\left(x,t\right)=\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\left(\exp\left(t\right)-1\right)$. Again the time dependence of $u$ is isn't controlled by parabolic Hölder norms of $f$ or $u_0$ of fixed order uniformly with respect to $T$.